# Photographing LEGO models

Tags: lighting, product-photography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best techniques for making great photographs of LEGO creations?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/what-are-the-best-techniques-for-making-great-photographs-of-lego-creations)

Has anyone got any tips for taking photos of your creations? Lighting seems to be the major issue for me, particularly glare from large flat surfaces, but I would welcome any tricks people have discovered to show off their models.

Comment: A good starting point would be: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/what-are-the-best-techniques-for-making-great-photographs-of-lego-creations